# post method rendering 403 forbidden page instead of executing post method code

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt

*note: I am new to Play Framework*

Using this [video tutorial and playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBTocaReFow&list=PLYPFxrXyK0Bx9SBkNhJr1e2-NlIq4E7ED&index=15), I manage to create a simple webapp.

**Problem:**

`POST` methods in routes file do not seem to execute the required POST code.

Given the routes file below, browsing to `localhost:{port}/user/register` requests a `GET`, thus rendering and returning the `register view`.

Filling in the `register view` fields, and clicking `submit`, refreshes the page (by clearing the input fields) and does show the expected "registered" text

If `method="post"` has been added to the `form` in the `register view`, an immediate `403 Forbidden page` page is displayed.

Why isn't the "registered" text being shown, what am I missing (doing wrong) ?

Routes file:

```
GET        /                     controllers.HomeController.index

GET        /user                 controllers.LoginController.index()
GET        /user/login           controllers.LoginController.login()
POST       /user/login           controllers.LoginController.doLogin()
GET        /user/register        controllers.LoginController.register()
POST       /user/register        controllers.LoginController.doRegister()

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET        /assets/*file         controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

Controllers:

```
HomeController
LoginController
```

LoginController methods:

```
public Result index() { return ok(views.html.user.index.render(User.getAllUsers())) } 
public Result login() { return ok(login.render()); }
public Result doLogin() { return ok("registered"); }
public Result register() { return ok(register.render()); }
public Result doRegister() { return ok("registered"); }
```

Register View:

```
@()

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Register new User</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Register User</h1>
        <br>
        <br>
        Enter Email Address: <input type="password" name="confirmPassword">
        Enter Password: <input type="password" name="confirmPassword">
        Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="confirmPassword">
        <br>
        <br>
        <form action="@routes.LoginController.doRegister()">
            <input type="submit" value="Register"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Console output error:

```
[warn] p.filters.CSRF - [CSRF] Check failed because no or invalid token found in body
[warn] p.filters.CSRF - [CSRF] Check failed with NoTokenInBody
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're correct you need to define the HTTP method (GET or POST) to be used when submitting the form data.

It's possible you're seen `Forbidden` because "By default, Play will require a CSRF check" [See here?](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaCsrf#Protecting-against-Cross-Site-Request-Forgery)

Add the CSRF token to the request like this:

```
@import helper._

 <form method="post" action="@CSRF(routes.LoginController.doRegister())">
    ...
```

Or in the body of the form:

```
<form method="post" action="@routes.LoginController.doRegister()">
    @CSRF.formField
    ...
```

Comment: I did extensive reading up on this topic (filters, etc) to get a beter idea what is causing the issue. I noticed in the documentation, there exists an option to disable the CSRF check for a specific route. This is done by  placing ` + nocsrf` above the `post` route in one's routes file (for every `post` method one needs bypassing for the CSRF filter. I shall apply your suggested method to include and make use of the CRSF filter, since it was a little vage. Thank you!

Comment: @KGCybeX that does work - but is a workaround and removes the safety which the CSRF provides. If you ever deploy, be sure to have the CSRF token in there with the check if you're doing a sensitive POST.