# How to pass along CSRF token in an AJAX post request for a form?

Tags: jquery, ajax, scala, playframework, csrf

I'm using Scala Play! 2.6 Framework, but that may not be the issue. I'm using their Javascript routing - and it seems to work ok, but it's having issues. I have a form, which when rendered produces this, with a CSRF token:

```
<form method="post" id="myForm" action="someURL">

<input name="csrfToken" value="5965f0d244b7d32b334eff840...etc" type="hidden">
  <input type="text" id="sometext">
  <button type="submit"> Submit! </button>

</form>
```

And here's roughly, my AJAX:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#myForm', function (event) {

 event.preventDefault();
   var data = {
    textvalue: $('#sometext').val()
   }
 var route = jsRoutes.controllers.DashboardController.postNewProject()
 $.ajax({
    url: route.url,
    type: route.type,
    data : JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType : 'application/json',
    success: function (data) { ...      },
    error: function (data) { ...  }
        })

});
```

But when I post this, I am getting an UNAUTHORIZED response back from my Server, and my console in IntelliJ is telling me the CSRF check is failing. How would I pass along the CSRF token in the request?

Comment: did you ever get this resolved?

Comment: Not really, but for now I turned off the CSRF check... DON'T DO

Comment: maybe this question of mine may help or provide assistance -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45017920/post-method-rendering-403-forbidden-page-instead-of-executing-post-method-code

Comment: Thanks - I had been having that issue - and the form I posted above follows a similar method by adding `@CSRF.formField` (I've just shown it post-render, as it is sent to the client). My issue now though is that it's not sending or checking for it when I POST through an AJAX request.

Comment: @KGCybeX I've managed to fix it, you may come across this issue later if you try to POST anything with AJAX- see my answer below.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Ok, after fighting this for a few hours and trying to decrypt Play's frequently-lacking-context-Documentation on the [subject](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaCsrf), I've got it.

So, from their docs:

> To allow simple protection for non browser requests, Play only checks
>   requests with cookies in the header. If you are making requests with
>   AJAX, you can place the CSRF token in the HTML page, and then add it
>   to the request using the `Csrf-Token` header.

And then there's no code or example. Thanks Play. Very descriptive. Anyway, here's how:

in your `view.html.formTemplate` you might write in IntelliJ:

```
@()
<form method="post" id="myForm" action="someURL">

@helper.CSRF.formField  <!-- This auto-generates a token for you -->
  <input type="text" id="sometext">
  <button type="submit"> Submit! </button>

</form>
```

And this will render like this when delivered to the client:

```
<form method="post" id="myForm" action="someURL">

<input name="csrfToken" value="5965f0d244b7d32b334eff840...etc" type="hidden">
  <input type="text" id="sometext">
  <button type="submit"> Submit! </button>

</form>
```

Ok, almost there, now we have to create our AJAX call. I have all of mine in a separate main.js file, but you could also put this in your `view.html.formTemplate` if you want.

```
$(document).on('submit', '#myForm', function (event) {

 event.preventDefault();
   var data = {
    myTextToPass: $('#sometext').val()
   }
 // LOOK AT ME! BETWEEN HERE AND
 var token =  $('input[name="csrfToken"]').attr('value')
    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Csrf-Token', token);
        }
    });
// HERE
 var route = jsRoutes.controllers.DashboardController.postNewProject()
 $.ajax({
    url: route.url,
    type: route.type,
    data : JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType : 'application/json',
    success: function (data) { ...      },
    error: function (data) { ...  }
        })

});
```

With this line:
`var token =  $('input[name="csrfToken"]').attr('value')`
You are plucking out the CSRF token auto generated in your form field and grabbing its value in a var to be used in your Javascript.

The other important chunk from all that AJAX is here:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Csrf-Token', token);
            }
        });
```

Using the `$.ajaxSetup`, you can set what's in the header. This is what you have to infer from their documentation:

> add it to the request using the Csrf-Token header.

Good luck! Let me know if this is clear.

---

**Note**: when using [lusca](https://github.com/krakenjs/lusca), use `X-CSRF-Token` instead of `Csrf-Token`.

Comment: Thanks! I pretty much wrote it that way because I know I'd need to one day reference it again myself.

Comment: Your answer is seriously helping others a lot! :)

Comment: @NateH06 What if you don't use "<form method="post" id="myForm" action="someURL">" and "@helper.CSRF.formField", but instead use "@CSRF(route.Something.something(something))" where "something" is a javascript variable that should be parsed into "@CSRF(route.Something.something(something))"? Is this even possible?

Comment: If you're trying to roll your own token using JS, I would avoid using their `@CSRF` helper call at all, I'm not sure if it takes parameters. Just generate the HTML on your own and insert the value as you see fit. `<input name="yourCsrfToken" value="route.Something(something) etc" type="hidden">` and then change the above var set to: `var token =  $('input[name="yourCsrfToken"]').attr('value') `

Comment: Works perfectly! I had to add 'X-CSRF-Token', because I am using lusca

Comment: I did this and I still ran into problems when making multiple Ajax calls for a SPA. To get my code to work I needed the approach described at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46456399/play-framework-2-6-csrf-and-session.

Answer (score 7):

From JSP

```
<form method="post" id="myForm" action="someURL">
    <input name="csrfToken" value="5965f0d244b7d32b334eff840...etc" type="hidden">    
</form>
```

This is the simplest way that worked for me after struggling for 3hrs, just get the token from input hidden field like this and while doing the AJAX request to just need to pass this token in header as follows:-

From JQuery

```
var token =  $('input[name="csrfToken"]').attr('value');
```

From plain Javascript

```
var token = document.getElementsByName("csrfToken").value;
```

Final AJAX Request

```
$.ajax({
          url: route.url,
          data : JSON.stringify(data),
          method : 'POST',
          headers: {
                        'X-CSRFToken': token 
                   },
          success: function (data) { ...      },
          error: function (data) { ...  }
});
```

Now you don't need to disable crsf security in web config, and also this will not give you 405( Method Not Allowed) error on console.

Hope this will help people..!!

Comment: This does help, but only if 'X-CSRFToken' is used (without the second dash that is)!

Answer (score 2):

> add it to the request using the `Csrf-Token` header.

Thanks **NateH06** for the header name! I was trying to send csrf token for a "delete" button with an ajax function call and I was stuck on the following:

```
@import helper._
....
<button id="deleteBookBtn" class="btn btn-danger"
        data-csrf-name="@helper.CSRF.getToken.name"
        data-csrf-value="@helper.CSRF.getToken.value"
        data-delete-url="@routes.BooksController.destroy(book.id)"
        data-redirect-url="@routes.HomeController.index()">Delete</button>
```

I wasn't able to add online js within the `onclick()` event because of a CSP set on play 2.6 too.

> Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'".

And on the JS file:

```
function sendDeleteRequest(event) {
  url = event.target.getAttribute("data-delete-url")
  redirect = event.target.getAttribute("data-redirect-url")
  csrfTokenName = event.target.getAttribute("data-csrf-name")
  csrfTokenValue = event.target.getAttribute("data-csrf-value")
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: "DELETE",
    beforeSend: function(request) {
      //'Csrf-Token' is the expected header name, not $csrfTokenName
      request.setRequestHeader(/*$csrfTokenName*/'Csrf-Token', csrfTokenValue);
    },
    success: function() {
      window.location = redirect;
    },
    error: function() {
      window.location.reload();
    }
  })
}

var deleteBookBtn = document.getElementById("deleteBookBtn");
if(deleteBookBtn) {
    deleteBookBtn.addEventListener("click", sendDeleteRequest);
}
```

After setting the header name as `'Csrf-Token'` the ajax call works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

In case it's of use to anyone else who is googling around trying to understand why they can't get the correct token to appear.... I've been struggling with the same issue for a Play backend/React frontend combination - and hence unable to (easily) use the token-in-htmlpage technique I eventually came across another solution for setting the current token in a cookie... simply add:

```
play.filters.csrf {
  cookie.name = "csrftoken"
}
```

to application.conf and the `csrftoken` cookie will be set to the token. I then used https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-cookie to grab the value in my JS code and send it back in the request header - not including the code here as it's React not jQuery as for the OP and don't want to confuse matters.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `Csrf-Token` header with `headers` option.

```js
$.ajax({
    url: '@routes.MyController.myPostAction()',
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
        'Csrf-Token': '@play.filters.csrf.CSRF.getToken.map(_.value)'
    },
    data: {
        name: '@name'
    },
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        location.reload();
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        debugger;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [Play Framework 2.6 Documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaCsrf#Plays-CSRF-protection), you may set a '`Csrf-Token`' Header with the token generated by Play:

> If you are making requests with AJAX, you can place the CSRF token in the HTML page, and then add it to the request using the `Csrf-Token` header.

Within a Scala-Template you can get the token-value using `@helper.CSRF.getToken.value`

Following [jQuerys Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) you may either set it once for all Ajax requests by configuring jQuery using [ajaxSetup](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/)

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Csrf-Token', '@helper.CSRF.getToken.value');
  }
});
```

or alternatively set the Header on every Request by configuring the `headers` object like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: route.url,
  ...
  headers: {
    'Csrf-Token': '@helper.CSRF.getToken.value'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**slim csrf gurd**, the way for passing csrf key and token in jQuery for slim application with twig

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, originalOptions, jqXHR){

        var allowedMethod = ["post", "put", "delete"];

        if (allowedMethod.includes(options.type.toLowerCase())  ) {
            // initialize `data` to empty string if it does not exist
            options.data = options.data || "";

            // add leading ampersand if `data` is non-empty
            options.data += options.data?"&":"";

            // add _token entry
            options.data += "{{csrf.keys.name}}={{csrf.name}}&{{csrf.keys.value}}={{csrf.value}}";
        }
    });
});
```