# Play Framework 2.6 CSRF and Session

Tags: scala, playframework, csrf

I got strange issue. I'm implementing cart functionality on my website and I use session to store cart positions. I have a POST action to add new position to cart, and I have CSRF filter enabled to secure website. I call it with ajax on a product page, so first call is okay, but second says Unauthorized and in logs there are `[CSRF] Check failed because no token found in headers for /cart`. But it has. I call it with:

```
 $("form").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/cart',
            method: 'POST',
            data: getCartPosition(),
            beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('Csrf-Token', $('input[name=csrfToken]').val());},
            success: function (data, textStatus) {
                alert('Added!');
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert('Error!');
            }
        });
    });
```

and I put CSRF token in template somewhere:

```
@CSRF.formField
```

and it's in request:

[image]

I have enabled this in config

```
play.filters.csrf.bypassCorsTrustedOrigins=true 
play.filters.hosts {
  # Allow requests to example.com, its subdomains, and localhost:9000
  allowed = ["localhost:9000", "localhost:4200"]
}
```

But what is strange that it seems it puts csrfToken in session, because after failed request I have session like this

```
Session(Map(cart -> {"positions":
[{"trackId":1},{"trackId":24},{"trackId":20}]}, 
username -> user, 
token -> 0639d0b0-e7c8-4e82-9aad-2a43044e72db, 
csrfToken -> e705413843ea96a6491a0e9e800ba36a712c4f70-1506542471068-0baeef7535eb9c889fb6fed2))
```

Idk why it's there, my add2cart action looks like:

```
private def cartAction(addToCartForm: Form[CartPosition], action: (Cart, CartPosition) => Cart)(implicit request: UserRequest[Any]) = {
    addToCartForm.fold(
      _ => BadRequest("Error!"),
      position => {
        getCart match {
          case Some(cart) => Ok("Ok").withSession("cart" -> Json.toJson(action(cart, position)).toString(), "username" -> request.session.get("username").getOrElse(""), "token" -> request.session.get("token").getOrElse(""))
          case _ => Ok("Ok, no").withSession("cart" -> Json.toJson(action(Cart(Seq.empty), position)).toString())
        }
      }
    )
  }

def addToCart() = guestAction { implicit request =>
    cartAction(addToCartForm.bindFromRequest, addCartPos)
  }
```

and addCartPos just adds position to json

Comment: Switched to GET and it works, but still hadn't figured it out why it's not working with POST

Comment: Actually I get csrfToken in session not only with cart, it just put it anywhere

Comment: I had a similar problem and I solved it with using `addingToSession` instead of `withSession`. I guess the latter will overwrite the session and clear the csrf token that was put in it when rendering the template. Not sure if it is the same problem you are having as I don't quite understand how the csrf mechanism work in Play.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've got same issue with Play 2.7.3.

In my case, the form is generated by the Twirl with the `csrf token` and because I'm using ajax to submit the form, I've copied the `csrf token` from the rendered form and pass it to the ajax header as writen in the Play's documentation.

The form can be submitted multiple times so I need to updated the token. Therefore I'm passing through ajax response new `csrf token` taken in the controller from `play.filters.csrf.CSRF.getToken.get.value`.

But unfortunatelly, the second submission failed as **cutoffurmind** mentioned.

And the fix is as described by **Knut Arne Vedaa** to add new token to the session. I did it by the `withSession` method.

So the controller response is looking like this:

```
 Ok(Json.obj(
    "status" -> (user != None),
    "notif" -> "Success login",
    "data" -> Map( 
       "adminUrl" -> "www.something ...", 
       "csrf" -> play.filters.csrf.CSRF.getToken.get.value
    )
 )).withSession(
    "uid" -> user.getOrElse(User()).id.toString,
    "csrfToken" -> play.filters.csrf.CSRF.getToken.get.value
 )
```

It doesn't look like an issue as Play Framework doesn't have session data kept on the server, so it is logical that the token has to be updated in the client site after the ajax request. The main issue is that it is not mentioned in the documentation (in the CSRF ajax section), what could be handy as people simply doesn't read the doc from A to Z in expected order.

Answer (score 3):

In my case the solution was to set the `play.filters.csrf.cookie.name` config option to a value other than null:

```
play.filters.csrf.cookie.name = csrf_token
```

Comment: This worked for me as well - I kept getting [CSRF] Check failed because no token found in headers until I set this property - do you know why this works? What is weird is that this worked in 2017 without setting the property. The docs are bad, it's not clear to me how the csrf protection interacts with cookies.

Comment: There are several types of CSRF protection available and some of them use cookies https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery.