# secure way to upload text and image in php

Tags: php, ajax, pdo, csrf, sql-injection

Just want to check how vulnerable are my scripts and projects. From the research of expert's blog and answer, I found possible attack and injection is based on

- **file types**
- **sql statements**
- **access to image folder in root,**
- **session**

I heard about Anti-CSRF token to prevent session hijacking. How can I pass CSRF token value from ajax form data.

I am not sure how much I am secure. Please guide me what I have to add in following scripts to improve security?

```
<?php
    if(!empty($_POST['heading']) && !empty($_POST['content']) && !empty($_POST['keytag']) && !empty($_POST['date'])){
        $query = '';
        if(!empty($_FILES['file']['name'])){
            $target_dir = "../images/news/";
            $img = basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
            $verifyimg = getimagesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
            $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($img,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
            $img_ext = end((explode('.', $img)));
            if($_FILES['file']['size'] > 200000){
                echo "File is too large";
                exit();
            }
            if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
                echo "Only jpg/png/gif image !";
                exit();
            }
            if($verifyimg['mime'] != 'image/png' && $verifyimg['mime'] != 'image/jpg' && $verifyimg['mime'] != 'image/jpeg' && $verifyimg['mime'] != 'image/gif') {
                echo "Image is not valid";
                exit;
            }
            else{
                $new_img = substr(md5(time()), 0, 10) . '.' . $img_ext;
                $target_file = $target_dir .$new_img;
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
                $query = $con->prepare('INSERT into news(heading, content, keytag, date, img) VALUES(:heading, :content, :keytag, :date, :new_img)');
                $query->bindParam(':new_img',$new_img);

            }
        }
        if(empty($_FILES['file']['name'])){
            $query = $con->prepare('INSERT into news(heading, content, keytag, date) VALUES(:heading, :content, :keytag, :date)');
        }
        $query->bindParam(':heading', $_POST['heading']);
        $query->bindParam(':content', $_POST['content']);
        $query->bindParam(':keytag', $_POST['keytag']);
        $query->bindParam(':date', $_POST['date']);
        if($query->execute()){
            echo "Successfully Inserted";
        };
    }
?>
```

**.htaccess**

To block direct access

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www\.your-domain\.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www\.your-domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(wav|swf|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|js|css)$ - [F,NC,L]
```

My main question is how to pass CSRF Token from ajax ?

**html**

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token"  value="<?php echo $_SESSION['_token']; ?>" />
<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
```

Ajax

```
<script>
    $(document).on('submit', '#form', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'upload.php',
            data: new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
        $("#file").change(function(){
            var file = this.files[0];
            var imagefile = file.type;
            var match= ["image/jpeg","image/png","image/jpg"];
            if(!((imagefile==match[0]) || (imagefile==match[1]) || (imagefile==match[2]))){
                alert('Please select a valid image file (JPEG/JPG/PNG).');
                $("#file").val('');
                return false;
            }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Okay, so what's broken? SO is designed for us to help us fix issues, if you need it reviewed, go to codereview.stackexchange, or for security, go to security.stackexchange - either way, this is not the best place for a "please review/bolster my security" question. There is likely people here who can answer this, but here is not the best place for it be answered

Comment: I suspect this is going to require a full code breakdown and therefore *may* be too broad for Stack Overflow - [infosec](https://security.stackexchange.com/) might be a better fit. However - if the question is just how to pass a CSRF prevention token via Ajax - just do it the same as you would any other piece of form data; it's validated in the receiving script which should then output a JSON representing the error if one occurs. You merely handle that in your JS callback.

Comment: @SamSwift웃 The question *"My main question is how to pass CSRF Token from ajax ?"* does not belong at Code Review however.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass along CSRF token in an AJAX post request for a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45470802/how-to-pass-along-csrf-token-in-an-ajax-post-request-for-a-form)

Comment: I had to be divided this question in two parts - Security review and CSRF token.  Hope [link](https://security.stackexchange.com) might be helpful. Thanks for everyone

Comment: @SamSwift웃 Do I have to delete this question from here to post in security.stackexchange  [link](https://security.stackexchange.com) ??

Comment: @AnandHmt - you don't have to delete to post to security, just copy it over, I'd personally recommend leaving what to do with this question up to mods, just note somewhere it's on security.stackexchange