# CSRF/Spring Security - 403 Error After Login via AJAX

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, csrf-protection

I'm encountering an issue when using CSRF protection with Spring Security 5.1.4.

I have set up a custom login page for the application.  When the user enters his or her credentials, an AJAX request is made.  The success handler performs its responsibilities and returns a JSON document in the response.  When the AJAX call succeeds, the screen is dynamically updated by removing the username and password fields and replacing them with a dropdown field and a Continue button.

When the user makes a selection from the dropdown and clicks the Continue button, the action on the form is changed and the form is submitted using the POST method.  The user is then to be directed to a home screen.  Unfortunately,  the application responds with a Forbidden (403) error.

When I modify the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter to disable CSRF protection, my login screen performs as expected.

Is there something I'm missing when I submit the form?  Note that I've included the CSRF parameter and token in a hidden field within the form element.

WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/css/**", "/images/**", "/js/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .successHandler(customAuthenticationHandler)
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .deleteCookies("JESSIONID")
                .permitAll();
    }

public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
}
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String logIn() {
    return "login-custom";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String home() {
    return "home";
}
```

JSP

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/workdaybsa/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript">

        function login() {
            $.ajax({
                url: $('#loginForm').attr('action'),
                type: 'POST',
                data: $('#loginForm').serialize(),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(response){
                    $('#loginSection').attr('style', 'display:none');
                    $('#selectionSection').removeAttr('style');
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert(status);
                    alert(error);
                }
           });
        }

        function proceed() {
            $('form').attr('action', 'home');
            $('form').submit();
        }
    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <form id="loginForm" action="login" method="post">

        <div id="loginSection">
            <p>
                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
            </p>
            <input type="button" value="Sign In" onclick="login()">
        </div>
        <div id="selectionSection" style="display:none">
            <select id="selection">
                <option value="">-- Select The Option --</option>
            </select>
            <input type="button" value="Continue" onclick="proceed()">
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" id="csrf" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>

    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSRF token is an anti forgery token that you'll need to pass back to your Spring Security on every request using Csrf-Token header attribute which you didn't include in your ajax call even though it's in a hidden input field. That's why the CSRF validation fails and throw a 403.

The solution is provided here [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45470802/how-to-pass-along-csrf-token-in-an-ajax-post-request-for-a-form)

To shamelessly copy paste the answer, this is what you need:

```
$.ajax({
  url: route.url,
  ...
  headers: {
    'Csrf-Token': $('#csrf").val()
  }
});
```

Comment: I should have pointed out that I already attempted to pass the CSRF information using headers: {$('#csrf').attr('name') : $('#csrf').val()} in my AJAX call, but this did not solve the problem.

Comment: I suppose you have also verified that csrf token is passed in along with your AJAX request? I was re-reading the guide to csrf https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-csrf a little and notice that you didn't include the <meta> tag to hold csrf in the code snippet. Maybe share your repo/minimal reproducible repo?

Comment: I tried adding the meta tags as well, but that also did not work for me.

Comment: I suppose you have also debugged and checked that the meta tags contain the expected values and you have inspected the header of your AJAX calls to ensure that all is working. Maybe share the stack trace?