# How to submit a blade.php form with AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

How should I handle the csrf_field() function when doing this with AJAX?

[here is a link to the project repo](https://github.com/tomkeane07/Laravel_shopper).

[Here is a link to the article which helped me write the code.](https://www.parthpatel.net/laravel-tutorial-for-beginner/)

I'm pretty sure I don't have to make too many changes to the code to handle the forms with **AJAX** instead of regular **blade.php** form submissions, but I'm unsure of the implementation

```
<form id="add_item" method="POST" action="/item">
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea name="item_name" placeholder='Enter your item'></textarea>  
                @if ($errors->has('item_name'))
                    <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('item_name') }}</span>
                @endif
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" >Add Item</button>
            </div>
            {{ csrf_field() }}
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also put csrf-token in header file like this...

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

then give one unique id to submit button... then after in JavaScript detect that click event. then after call ajax on click event of submit button

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    // url: "{{ route('admin.users')}}" + id,
    // url : '/admin/users/',
    url: "{{url('admin/users/')}}", // you can pass url using url() OR as simple url OR Route name also
    headers: {
       'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') //get the Csrf token from header
    },
    data: { id: id, },   //pass here all data which you want to pass to controller
    success: function (data) {
         console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

get the csrf value using

```
var token =  $('input[name="csrfToken"]').attr('value');
```

and append it to the header

```
$.ajax({
      url: route.url,
      data : JSON.stringify(data),
      method : 'POST',
      headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-Token': token 
               },
      success: function (data) { ...      },
      error: function (data) { ...  }
```

});

you can read more about it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51964045/9890762

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED.

I had to remove the 'type' attribute from the form as ajax is being used instead,
and ensure the ajax functions are at /**public**/js/file.js

Then, to make the changes available to the folder resources

> npm run dev

```
        <form id="add_item_form" action="/item">

            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea id="add_item_name" placeholder='Enter your item'></textarea>  
                @if ($errors->has('item_name'))
                    <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('item_name') }}</span>
                @endif
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <button id="ajaxSubmit_add">Add Item</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```