# Why getting the "CSRF token is missing" when is already plugged in template?

Tags: python, django, ajax, forms, cookies

I wanted to post a login form through AJAX Post request using JQuery:

Even i sent the csrf token along the others however somehow Django fails to validify with the token inside a cookie.

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('submit', 'form', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'login',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                username: $('input[name=username]').val(),
                password: $('input[name=password]').val(),
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
            }),
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
            }
           
        });
    });
```

Here is the view function that url goes to:

```
def login(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            username = request.POST["username"]
            password = request.POST["password"]
            user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user:
                auth.login(request, user)
                return HttpResponse("Successfully logged in!")
        
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Username or Password is incorrect")
        
        else:
            return render(request, "login.html")
```

1.I thought that it would be solved if i didn't use {% csrf_token %} and i tried to get token and send to be rendered in the template in view.py:

```
from django.middleware.csrf import get_token 
csrf_token = get_token(request)
return render(request, 'login.html', {'csrf_token':csrf_token}
```

it didn't solve the problem i still got that error.

2.I thought that it might be something related to the csrf cookie value. Everytime i registered a user to the database just the sessionid cookie's value changed and the csrf cookie remained same but i don't know how can i go about that.

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Post full error. Post your config values for `the CSRF_USE_SESSIONS` and `CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY`

Answer (score 0):

In django template, there should be a **template tag** called **{% csrf_token %}** in the form tag to pass the csrf_token. e.g

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %} // this is mandatory for POST requests.
    // other tags 
    <input type="text" name='text' />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

After doing this you can do like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45490899/12098337