# How to disable play 2.6 CSRFFilter

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.2

I was recently migrated to play 2.6, and im getting 403 responses when calling my api from postman that have something to do with filters.

at first when I run my service I got this error

> [warn] 13:40:58.654 - play.filters.hosts.AllowedHostsFilter - Host not
>   allowed: 14.1.90.128:9000

so I added in the application.conf:

```
play.filters.hosts {
  allowed = ["."]
}
```

and it fixed the issue, but I was never forced to do that...

and not im getting this error trying to get to an action api method:

> [warn] 20:04:23.230 - play.filters.CSRF - [CSRF] Check failed because
>   no token found in headers

wierdly enough, a get method works and post gives the above error...

I know it have something to do with rest security but never was forced to think about it, how to I go about this? 
I know filters

Comment: As pointed in docs: >>Note: As of Play 2.6.x, the Allowed Hosts filter is included in Play’s list of default filters that are applied automatically to projects. << https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/AllowedHostsFilter - it's pretty well explained.

Comment: Duplicate see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45017920/post-method-rendering-403-forbidden-page-instead-of-executing-post-method-code/45023117#45023117

Comment: Possible duplicate of [post method rendering 403 forbidden page instead of executing post method code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45017920/post-method-rendering-403-forbidden-page-instead-of-executing-post-method-code)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

to disable play CSRFFilter add to your application conf:

```
play.filters.disabled+=play.filters.csrf.CSRFFilter
```